# Can I add additional module to drupal distribution (all inclusive)?

Tags: distributions

I have a SSO module I need to add to Open Social distribution. Can I add this additional module to the distribution (all inclusive)?

Comment: Are you going to contribute the distribution or just for your own project?

Comment: For my own project alone

Answer (score 0):

In your installation you can add the module just like any other module yes.

If you want to add id to the distribution itself, you would effectivly make a new distribution based on Open Social with the module added - please read the guidelines [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2210443) to learn how to add it.